# how to make paging for this custom rest API?

Tags: php, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I used this to get best selling product from woocommerce and return the product data in REST API

but i need to make a pagination system so user can define witch page must show.

```
function featureproduct(){
$prdtc=wc_get_featured_product_ids();
$array=array();
$i=0;
    foreach ($prdtc as $id)
    {
        $res = wc_get_product( $id);
        $array[$i]=array(
$id,
 $res->get_name(),
$res->get_price(),
get_the_post_thumbnail_url($id),
get_permalink($id)
);
    $i++;
}
    echo json_encode($array,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
}
```

I need something like that wp-json Used
for example:

```
/wp-json/wc/v3/products?per_page=10&page=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was change my codes to this :

```
function featureproduct($tedad1){
    $tedad=$tedad1['tedad'];
    $offset=$tedad1['offset'];
global $wpdb;
$query="
SELECT id FROM `wp_posts` WHERE post_type='product' 
AND post_status='pending' 
ORDER BY post_date ASC LIMIT ".$offset.", ".$tedad."";

$prdtc=$wpdb->get_results($query);
$array=array();
$i=0;
foreach ($prdtc as $id)
{
    $res = wc_get_product( $id->id);
    $array[$i]=array(
$id->id, $res->get_name(),
$res->get_price(),
get_the_post_thumbnail_url($id->id),
get_permalink($id->id));

    $i++;
}
    echo json_encode($array,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

}
```

with "LIMIT" and that two parameter I be able to do something like paging